# how can i use rotated proxy with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

i wrote this in setting.py after `pip install scrapy-rotating-proxies`

```
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = ['http://209.50.52.162:9050']
 
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
 
'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620
 }
```

then if i run spider like this  `scrapy crawl test`
it show this.

```
2021-05-03 15:03:32 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] WARNING: No proxies available; marking all proxies as unchecked
2021-05-03 15:03:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-05-03 15:03:50 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 1, mean backoff time: 0s)
2021-05-03 15:03:53 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://209.50.52.162:9050> is DEAD
2021-05-03 15:03:53 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.google.com> with another proxy (failed 3 times, max retries: 5)
```

how can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the message in your logs:

```
DEBUG: Proxy <http://209.50.52.162:9050> is DEAD
```

You need to add more proxies as shown in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-rotating-proxies/):

```
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = [
    'proxy1.com:8000',
    'proxy2.com:8031',
    # ...
]
```

You can get a list of proxies from many [sites](https://free-proxy-list.net/).